# Modal with WKWebView closes on text field focus

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiviewrepresentable

I have a simple sheet that contains UIViewRepresentable. It opens a web page and not much more than that. I have this module in two parts of my app. One works great, but another when I focus on a text field, immediately closes the modal and gives me messages (below the question). I see it's a problem with auto layout, but I'm on SwiftUI, so what can go wrong with a single web view?

What am I doing wrong?

```
    .sheet(item: $addURL) { url in
       WebView(callback: { _ in viewModel.fetchCards() }, url: url)}
```

I know it's too long to read, but maybe it will help:

```
2021-02-21 02:11:34.423786+0100 CafeApp[54097:3012811] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c7c50 h=--& v=--& _UIToolbarContentView:0x7f86c0e58860.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001cc7d0 H:|-(0)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f86c0e51e20]   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x7f86c0e58860 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001cc820 H:[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f86c0e51e20]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x7f86c0e58860 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c55e0 'IB_Leading_Leading' H:|-(0)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f86c2034c10]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2034490 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c5c70 'IB_Leading_Leading' H:|-(>=5)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f86c2035f20]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2035d50 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c5630 'IB_Trailing_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f86c2034c10]-(>=8)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2034490 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c5cc0 'IB_Trailing_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f86c2035f20]-(>=5)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2035d50 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c6a30 'TB_Leading_Leading' H:|-(8)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f86c2037880'Done']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2036860 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c6a80 'TB_Trailing_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f86c2037880'Done']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2036860 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c6f80 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x600001bd1340'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading == _UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2034490.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c72f0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x600001bd1340'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing == _UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2036860.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c7340 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2034490]-(0)-[UIView:0x7f86c2035be0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c7390 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x7f86c2035be0]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2035d50]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c73e0 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2035d50]-(0)-[UIView:0x7f86c20366f0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c7430 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x7f86c20366f0]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2036860]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001cc640 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600001bd1340'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f86c0e51e20 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001cc6e0 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x600001bd1340'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f86c0e51e20 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c5630 'IB_Trailing_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f86c2034c10]-(>=8)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2034490 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2021-02-21 02:11:34.425675+0100 CafeApp[54097:3012811] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c7c50 h=--& v=--& _UIToolbarContentView:0x7f86c0e58860.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001cc7d0 H:|-(0)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f86c0e51e20]   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x7f86c0e58860 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001cc820 H:[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f86c0e51e20]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x7f86c0e58860 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c5c70 'IB_Leading_Leading' H:|-(>=5)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f86c2035f20]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2035d50 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c5cc0 'IB_Trailing_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f86c2035f20]-(>=5)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2035d50 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c6a30 'TB_Leading_Leading' H:|-(8)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f86c2037880'Done']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2036860 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c6a80 'TB_Trailing_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f86c2037880'Done']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2036860 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c6f80 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x600001bd1340'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading == _UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2034490.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c72f0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x600001bd1340'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing == _UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2036860.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c7340 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2034490]-(0)-[UIView:0x7f86c2035be0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c7390 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x7f86c2035be0]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2035d50]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c73e0 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2035d50]-(0)-[UIView:0x7f86c20366f0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c7430 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x7f86c20366f0]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2036860]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001cc640 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600001bd1340'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f86c0e51e20 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001cc6e0 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x600001bd1340'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f86c0e51e20 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c5cc0 'IB_Trailing_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f86c2035f20]-(>=5)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2035d50 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2021-02-21 02:11:34.426712+0100 CafeApp[54097:3012811] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c7c50 h=--& v=--& _UIToolbarContentView:0x7f86c0e58860.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001cc7d0 H:|-(0)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f86c0e51e20]   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x7f86c0e58860 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001cc820 H:[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f86c0e51e20]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x7f86c0e58860 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c6a30 'TB_Leading_Leading' H:|-(8)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f86c2037880'Done']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2036860 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c6a80 'TB_Trailing_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f86c2037880'Done']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2036860 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c6f80 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x600001bd1340'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading == _UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2034490.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c72f0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x600001bd1340'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing == _UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2036860.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c7340 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2034490]-(0)-[UIView:0x7f86c2035be0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c7390 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x7f86c2035be0]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2035d50]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c73e0 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2035d50]-(0)-[UIView:0x7f86c20366f0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c7430 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x7f86c20366f0]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2036860]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001cc640 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600001bd1340'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f86c0e51e20 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001cc6e0 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x600001bd1340'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f86c0e51e20 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c6a80 'TB_Trailing_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f86c2037880'Done']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2036860 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2021-02-21 02:11:34.428153+0100 CafeApp[54097:3012811] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c7cf0 h=--& v=--& _UIToolbarContentView:0x7f86c0e58860.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001cc870 V:|-(0)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f86c0e51e20]   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x7f86c0e58860 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001cc8c0 _UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f86c0e51e20.bottom == _UIToolbarContentView:0x7f86c0e58860.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000138500 UIImageView:0x7f86c2035a10.centerY == _UIModernBarButton:0x7f86c2034c10.centerY   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c58b0 'IB_Baseline_Baseline' _UIModernBarButton:0x7f86c2034c10.lastBaseline == UILayoutGuide:0x600001bbd5e0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c5900 'IB_Top_Top' V:|-(>=0)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f86c2034c10]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2034490 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c5b30 'UIButtonBar.maximumAlignmentSize' _UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2034490.height == UILayoutGuide:0x600001bd1340'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.height   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001cc690 'UIView-bottomMargin-guide-constraint' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x600001bd1340'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f86c0e51e20 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c5810 'UIView-bottomMargin-guide-constraint' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x600001bbd5e0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(11)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2034490 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001cc5f0 'UIView-topMargin-guide-constraint' V:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600001bd1340'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f86c0e51e20 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000138500 UIImageView:0x7f86c2035a10.centerY == _UIModernBarButton:0x7f86c2034c10.centerY   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2021-02-21 02:11:34.429076+0100 CafeApp[54097:3012811] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c7cf0 h=--& v=--& _UIToolbarContentView:0x7f86c0e58860.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001cc870 V:|-(0)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f86c0e51e20]   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x7f86c0e58860 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001cc8c0 _UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f86c0e51e20.bottom == _UIToolbarContentView:0x7f86c0e58860.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001ca8f0 UIImageView:0x7f86c2036520.centerY == _UIModernBarButton:0x7f86c2035f20.centerY   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c5f40 'IB_Baseline_Baseline' _UIModernBarButton:0x7f86c2035f20.lastBaseline == UILayoutGuide:0x600001bbd500'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c5f90 'IB_Top_Top' V:|-(>=0)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f86c2035f20]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2035d50 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c61c0 'UIButtonBar.maximumAlignmentSize' _UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2035d50.height == UILayoutGuide:0x600001bd1340'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.height   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001cc690 'UIView-bottomMargin-guide-constraint' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x600001bd1340'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f86c0e51e20 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c5ea0 'UIView-bottomMargin-guide-constraint' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x600001bbd500'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(11)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2035d50 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001cc5f0 'UIView-topMargin-guide-constraint' V:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600001bd1340'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f86c0e51e20 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001ca8f0 UIImageView:0x7f86c2036520.centerY == _UIModernBarButton:0x7f86c2035f20.centerY   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2021-02-21 02:11:34.430070+0100 CafeApp[54097:3012811] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c7cf0 h=--& v=--& _UIToolbarContentView:0x7f86c0e58860.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001cc870 V:|-(0)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f86c0e51e20]   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x7f86c0e58860 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001cc8c0 _UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f86c0e51e20.bottom == _UIToolbarContentView:0x7f86c0e58860.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001d58b0 UIButtonLabel:0x7f86c203a690.centerY == _UIModernBarButton:0x7f86c2037880'Done'.centerY + 1.5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c6c10 'TB_Baseline_Baseline' _UIModernBarButton:0x7f86c2037880'Done'.lastBaseline == UILayoutGuide:0x600001bbd960'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c6c60 'TB_Top_Top' V:|-(>=0)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f86c2037880'Done']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2036860 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c6ee0 'UIButtonBar.maximumAlignmentSize' _UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2036860.height == UILayoutGuide:0x600001bd1340'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.height   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001cc690 'UIView-bottomMargin-guide-constraint' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x600001bd1340'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f86c0e51e20 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001c6b70 'UIView-bottomMargin-guide-constraint' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x600001bbd960'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(11)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f86c2036860 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001cc5f0 'UIView-topMargin-guide-constraint' V:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600001bd1340'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f86c0e51e20 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001d58b0 UIButtonLabel:0x7f86c203a690.centerY == _UIModernBarButton:0x7f86c2037880'Done'.centerY + 1.5   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2021-02-21 02:11:34.497772+0100 CafeApp[54097:3012811] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2021-02-21 02:11:34.497881+0100 CafeApp[54097:3012811] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2021-02-21 02:11:35.041365+0100 CafeApp[54097:3012811] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=3 "Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing" UserInfo={RBSAssertionAttribute=<RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.webkit" name:"Background" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing}>
2021-02-21 02:11:35.041769+0100 CafeApp[54097:3012811] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11b1fef80 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS Background assertion 'WebProcess Background Assertion' for process with PID 54102, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=3 "Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing" UserInfo={RBSAssertionAttribute=<RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.webkit" name:"Background" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing}
2021-02-21 02:11:35.059422+0100 CafeApp[54097:3012811] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}>
2021-02-21 02:11:35.059608+0100 CafeApp[54097:3012811] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11b1fe000 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS Background assertion 'WebProcess Background Assertion' for process with PID 54102, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}
```

The code of WKWebView:

```
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable{
    let callback: (URL)->()
    let url: URL

    func makeCoordinator() -> WebView.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    var request: URLRequest {
        URLRequest(url: url)
    }

    private let webview = WKWebView()

    fileprivate func loadRequest(in webView: WKWebView) {
        webView.load(request)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<WebView>) -> WKWebView {
        webview.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        webview.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        webview.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            webview.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        
        loadRequest(in: webview)
        return webview
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<WebView>) {
        loadRequest(in: uiView)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        let parent: WebView

        init(_ parent: WebView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
            if let url = navigationAction.request.url, url.valueOf("success") != nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    self?.parent.callback(url)
                }
                
                decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.allow)
            } else {
                decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.allow)
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: I will say that those errors are not uncommon in SwiftUI and are usually of little concern. It *probably* has more to do with your web view (is it trying to show an alert?) or your view model and something refreshing the surrounding view. Can you post reproducible code?

Comment: I know, that's the problem. Edited post with the code

Comment: In your question you say "One works great, but another when I focus on a text field", but there are no text fields mentioned in any of the code (including the new stuff). Also, not sure what's happening when the callback runs. Can you provide a way for other users to reproduce this problem? Without it, it's going to be pretty hard to answer the question.

Comment: This web view is called in settings in the app and during the process of checkout of the order. It goes to the webpage that contains a field for entering text. And when user focuses on it, in case of checkout module in the app, it immediately dismisses with this error

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! The reason was in the publisher that received keyboard height to make an offset for the textfield. As far as I get it, the view entirely redraws itself when changing any of its properties. And it redraws also its sheets. So I wrote a condition to change the view only when there is no modals there:

```
.onReceive(Publishers.keyboardHeight) {
    if typeOfModal == nil {
        self.keyboardHeight = $0
    }
}
```